# jsf outcome error but not declared

Tags: jsf

my jsf pages show error

```
unable to find matching navigation case with from view id for action 'index'
unable to find matching navigation case with from view id for action 'login'
```

but i never declare any outcome index and login, even from faces-config.
but it's showing in every page

here is my jsf

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:lcg="http://www.lassitercg.com/jsf">
<f:metadata>
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{bean.bean_id}"></f:viewParam>
<f:event listener="#{bean.init}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
</f:metadata>
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<ui:composition template="../layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">          
        <h:form id="form_id">
            <h:messages id="form_messages" style="color:red;margin:8px;"></h:messages>              
            <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submitForm}"></p:commandButton>
            <p:button outcome="cancel" value="Cancel"></p:button>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any `UICommand` components in the page ?

Comment: i don't think so. But here is a strange part of it. My code runs well on my computer, but when i move it to my friends computer, this error exist

Comment: I assume you didn't provide the complete errors' expressions. If so, please post them right in addition to the `faces-config` file.